# Prove $|d_{s}(u)-d_{s}(v)|\leq1$ in BFS

Tags: algorithms, graphs, breadth-first-search

Trying to prove the following problem:

> Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and vertex $s\in V$, prove that: $\forall (u,v)\in E,\ |d_{s}(u)-d_{s}(v)|\leq1$ where $d_s(v)$ is the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ in BFS.

What I did: Let assume that it's isn't true, meaning there is $(u,v)\in E$ so $|d_{s}(u)-d_{s}(v)|>1$. Lets run BFS on graph $G$. If in BFS process there is edge $(u,v)$, this means that $d_{s}(u)+1=d_{s}(v)$ so $|d_{s}(u)-d_{s}(v)|=1$ which contradicts $|d_{s}(u)-d_{s}(v)|>1$. This means that there is at least one edge $w\in V$, in the path from $u$ to $v$.

Now I'm stuck. I don't come empty handed, I have the following theorems:

1. Given graph $G=(V,E)$ and vertex $s\in V$, for each edge $(u,v)\in E$ we have $\delta\left(s,v\right)\leq\delta\left(s,u\right)+1$ where $\delta(s,v)$ is the shortest path between $s$ and $v$ (or $\infty$ if no such path) in graph $G$ (note the difference between $\delta$ which on $G$ and $d$ which on BFS).
2. For each vertex $v\in V$ we get $d(v)=\delta(s,v)$ in BFS.

I think I might need to use those two theorems here but I don't see it. My problem is that there is **at least one** vertex $w$ and not exactly one. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is quite confusing:

> There is at least one edge $w \in V$

Is it an edge or a vertex?

Maybe it would be easier for you to look at some edge $(u,v) \in E$ and think about the moment in time $\tau$, when the BFS algorithm reached either $u$ or $v$ for the first time (it could reach them both at the same time).